# How to make an array filter return AND results instead of OR in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Currently my code shows images based on what check boxes a user selects. The array treatments[i] shows everything they check (this OR this OR this). It builds on itself. What I want is an AND situation. Currently if a user clicks on shutters, bathroom, contemporary, the results shows all images that have shutters and all images that are of bathrooms and all images that are contemporary.  I want to only show images of contemporary bathrooms that have shutters.

Here is the current code:

```
function showFilteredImages() {

     var productChoice = [...new Set(productSelect)];
     var roomChoice = [...new Set(roomSelect)];
     var styleChoice = [...new Set(styleSelect)];

        $(".treatment").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('filtered');
        });


        for (var i=0; i<treatments.length; i++){
            for (var j=0; j<productChoice.length; j++){
                if (treatments[i].product.indexOf(productChoice[j]) !== -1){
                    treatments[i].$elem.addClass('filtered');
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (var j=0; j<roomChoice.length; j++){
                if (treatments[i].room.indexOf(roomChoice[j]) !== -1){
                    treatments[i].$elem.addClass('filtered');
                    break;
                }         
            }

            for (var j=0; j<styleChoice.length; j++){
                if (treatments[i].style.indexOf(styleChoice[j]) !== -1){
                    treatments[i].$elem.addClass('filtered');
                    break;
                }         
            }
       
        $('.treatment').each(function(index, el){
                if(!$(el).hasClass('filtered')){

                    $(el).hide();
                }   
                else{
                    $(el).show();
                }        
            }); 
    }
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
for (var i=0; i<treatments.length; i++){
            for (var j=0; j<productChoice.length; j++){
                if (treatments[i].product.indexOf(productChoice[j]) !== -1){
                    for (var k=0; j<roomChoice.length; j++){
                        if (treatments[i].room.indexOf(roomChoice[k]) !== -1){
                            for (var l=0; j<styleChoice.length; j++){
                                if (treatments[i].style.indexOf(styleChoice[l]) !== -1){
                                    treatments[i].$elem.addClass('filtered');
                                      
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you give us a piece of HTML so that we have a reproducable base.

Comment: We don't need any HTML, but we do need to know what the `Set` objects are referencing, as well as the `treatments` array (since you're doing `.$elem` on each one).

Comment: ...it sure seems like you can do everything in a single iteration of `treatments`.

Comment: ...and why are you doing this: `[...new Set(roomSelect)]`. You're taking something, making it into a `Set`, and then turning that set into a Array.

Comment: Please can you tell me what is inside `treatments` array and how the user's selections are saved in it?

Comment: Hi slappy, the ...new Set() deletes all the duplicates and creates a new array

Comment: But why not use the Set? They exist to avoid having to iterate to find one.

Comment: Code-Lover, all the image are in treatments.  When a user selects an image, the class "filtered" is added to the treatment class then the code will go through each image and the ones that have class filtered will show, the others will hide.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
function showFilteredImages() {
    let productChoice = [...new Set(productSelect)];
    let roomChoice = [...new Set(roomSelect)];
    let styleChoice = [...new Set(styleSelect)];

    $(".treatment").each(() => $(this).removeClass("filtered"));

    let choices = [productChoice, roomChoice, styleChoice];

    // the "loop1" is the name of the loop, we need to name it so we can skip an iteration from a nested loop inside it;
    loop1:
    for (let i = 0; i < treatments.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < choices.length; j++) {
            let choice = choices[j];
            for (let k = 0; k < choice.length; k++) {
                if (treatments[i].product.indexOf(choice[j]) === -1) {
                    // if treatement doesn't have this choice option we just skip it;
                    // here we abort on this iteration of "loop1";
                    // if we didn't name it "loop1", the the code would continue just the loop above this one;
                    continue loop1;
                }
            }
        }
        // if we reached this point, it means the "treatement" has all the choices desired;
        // it has product, room and style;
        // so we add the class filtered to it;
        treatments[i].$elem.addClass("filtered");
    }

    $(".treatment").each(function (index, el) {
        if (!$(el).hasClass("filtered")) {
            $(el).hide();
        } else {
            $(el).show();
        }
    });
}
```

### Explanation

- First, I grouped the choice groups in one array `choices` to make easy to loop though them
- Instead of checking if an element (treatement) is within selection, we check if it isn't, and if it doesn't have one of the critereas we want we skip it.
- after the choices loop, we add the class `filtered` to the `treatement`'s that passed all the criterias.

Comment: Bit more simple than what I was doing.  Thank you. Let me give it a try

Comment: Well, it let me choose the checkbox for shutters and showed all the images that are shutters but that was it. Was not able to check any boxes for rooms or styles

Answer (score 1):

If `treatments` is a list of elements, and so are the sets you have, then your code should just iterate `treatments` once, and check each set to see if it exists therein. You can also show/hide in that single iteration.

Most of the data lacks definition, but I'm going to assume that each `Set` holds the data in question, so that we don't need to convert it to an Array.

```
function showFilteredImages() {

    // Let's use these sets
    var productChoice = new Set(productSelect);
    var roomChoice = new Set(roomSelect);
    var styleChoice = new Set(styleSelect);

    // Remove the "filtered" class and hide them all
    $(".treatment").removeClass("filtered").hide();

    // Filter down to the ones meeting the AND condition,
    //   and then add the "filtered" class and show them
    treatments
      .filter(t => 
        t.product.some(item => productChoice.has(item)) &&
        t.room.some(item => roomChoice.has(item))       &&
        t.style.some(item => styleChoice.has(item))
      )
      .forEach(t => t.$elem.addClass("filtered").show())
}
```

If the only purpose of the "filtered" class was to mark them just so you could re-select them again, it's no longer needed since we're doing all the work immediately.

---

EDIT: I removed the helper function, since it didn't really make things any shorter or clearer.

Comment: the check boxes are dynamically created with data from the database: products, rooms, styles.  Then I pass them to showFilteredImages and do a [...new Set] that deletes any duplicate products, rooms, styles and puts them into a new array

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Yes, each set holds all the data in question.  Example: productChoice has Blinds, Drapes, Shades, Shutters, Valance.  roomChoice has Bathroom, Bedroom, kitchen, Livingroom, etc

Comment: Yeah, that's the nice thing about sets. You get to do a constant time lookup instead of a full iteration over a list. Makes things shorter too.

Comment: Great!!  I was actually going to remove it.